# Embedding PDF on website - without uploading to other service

Tags: pdf, web, embedding, documents

On our site we use Google's document viewer to let users view PDF and other documents in the browser. But Google's viewer is not very good, when used without being Google. Quite often it doesn't show anything, and the limit for the PDF file is around 10/20mb. The main issue is that it quite often just doesn't show any files.

So, we're looking for a way to show pdf (and other documents) on our site. It would be great if it could be done without us having to upload it to another service as this complicates the process.

The pricing is not an issue, so even if you know an expensive service, it would be great to let us know.

Or if anyone has other solutions then it would be great to hear of that too.

Thanks,

Tobias

Answer (score 0):

Through another source we were suggested to use Scribd, and our first tests shows that it works great. The documentation is good-ish so it's easy enough to set up.

Comment: Can you use Scribd's viewer without uploading your docs to Scribd first?